# Recommendations for reducing the ViewState size on a legacy system

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, optimization, drop-down-menu, viewstate

I've looked up ways to reduce the ViewState:

- [Viewstate Optimisations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345608/viewstate-optimisations)
- [Strategies for reducing ViewState size in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944218/strategies-for-reducing-viewstate-size-in-asp-net)

However, due to the situation I'm in, I need the quickest and most effective ways to reduce the ViewState size. The legacy system I'm working on is bloated and routinely has a ViewState that's 800Kb+ on multiple postbacks.

For example, I'm pretty sure populating drop down lists with 100+ items on multiple post backs is one of the culprits, correct?

Any suggestions/advice would be appreciated.

**Edit 1**
Disabling the ViewState entirely doesn't appear feasible. It breaks all of the controls, of which there are many, rendering the pages unusable. If this is the best approach, how should I go about handling all the broken controls?

Comment: I know you are looking for the fastest way, but here are a couple suggestions. Replace Web Controls with their html equivilents when possible? Also, if you use a lot of panels, replace them with divs instead. Disable viewstate on controls that don't need it (this can be applied via page directive too if it ends up being all the controls on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at compressing the view state as described on [this code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14733/ViewState-Compression) page.

Note: I have not tried this but it seems like it should work.

Comment: Definitely the quickest reduction in ViewState size. I got a 70% reduction implementing the VB.NET version of this solution. That said, other improvements are certainly needed. Thank you!

Comment: Compressing the ViewState doesn't necessarily result in HTTP reductions. Remember that HTTP already can (and should be!) using deflate. A "pre-compressed" ViewState may therefore be [slightly] less compressible .. so check the *real* numbers sent.

Answer (score 5):

If you have drop-down lists with many items on them, and if the content of these dropdown lists can be retrieved easily on page postbacks, then this content should NOT be put into viewstate.  Instead, the dropdown list should be re-populated on the server on each postback. The classic example of this is a dropdown list containing the list of 50 states.  It make NO sense to put this content into viewstate.  This data can be cached on the server and used to repopulate the dropdown list on each postback, instead of passing this data back and forth to the client on each round trip.

So how do you bind content to a dropdown list without having it added to viewstate, and without turning off viewstate for the control?  The answer lies in an understanding of the ASP.Net eventing pipeline.  Viewstate tracking beings when the TrackViewState() method is called after the OnInit page event.  Any changes to programmatically make to a control after TrackViewState() has executed gets put into viewstate.  So if you are databinding your dropdown list in the Page_Load event, the entire content of the dropdown list will get put into viewstate, which you often do not want.

Thus if you do not want your dropdown list content to be serialized into viewstate, you must databind BEFORE the TrackViewState() method is executed.  The best place to do this is in the Init event for the dropdown list.  So to make a long story short, populate your dropdown list in its Init, and the drop-down list content will NOT be serialized into viewstate.  Of course, since the content is not in viewstate, you will need to re-populate it on every postback. However, if the content is cached and is cheap to retrieve (as is the case, for example, with the list of 50 states) then this is not a problem.

Example:  Say you have a dropdown list named "dropDownList1", and you can retrieve a List containing the content for the list in a method called GetData().  You can populate this list in the page_load event:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Content of dropdown list will be serialized into viewstate
        dropDownList1.DataSource = GetData();
        Page.DataBind();
    }
```

but if you do this, the content will be serialized into viewstate.  If you populate the list in its Init event:

```
    protected void dropDownList1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Content of dropdown list will NOT be serialized into viewstate
       GetData().ForEach(item => this.dropDownList1.Items.Add(item));
    }
```

the content will NOT be serialized into viewstate. As long as it is cheap to retrieve this content, you should do it this way.

For more information on this, see [this excellent article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) on Infinities Loop.  This is the best article I have ever seen on viewstate, and by understanding the content of this article we were able to start using viewstate more intelligently on our web pages and dramatically reduce our viewstate size.

Comment: This has been tremendously helpful, especially the article. One problem I'm running into now is that I'm populating the drop down using current user information which I can't access until after the page load. Still experimenting though...

Comment: Yes, that can be a problem.  By loading dropdown lists before TrackViewState executes, you have to move pretty early in the ASP.Net event pipeline, and sometimes some things are not available.  Usually if you think about it for a while you can find some work-around for issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest and most effective way would be to turn off view state entirely:

```
<system.web>
    <pages enableViewState="false" />
```

You can also turn it off for individual pages:

```
private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.EnableViewState = false;
}
```

Comment: Would this also effectively break the pages?

Comment: Maybe, but you could see if they run faster.  And then you would know if ViewState is the culprit or if you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I know it's the problem. When I view the page source the `input` tag with `id="__VIEWSTATE"` is usually pretty large.

Comment: Confirmed. Disabling the ViewState breaks all the controls on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are storing your sessions(Database stored preferably), the amount of traffic the page gets, and the amount of memory your server has (if you are using InProc sessions), you could store the viewstate in the session. It's quite easy to do, downside is there are pitfalls and it won't work for all sites.

Here is a good article outlining the basics of the process and what some of the downsides/pitfalls can be:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheSessionObjectAndMoreWrongheadedness.aspx